# Timezone codes conversion between SQL server and Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server which stores the TimeZone codes as the format listed here: [TimeZone Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). I wonder if there is a way to get this TimeZone code correctly in Java using the method `TimeZone.getTimeZone("")`. As the TimeZone codes in Java is not the same as it is in SQL ([Available TimeZones in Java](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html)).

Or is there a way to return the time offset in SQL server by the TimeZone code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's mapping information between Windows time zone IDs and [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) IDs in [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) - it's reasonably easy to read the XML, and you may well find there's a Java library around to parse this for you.

However, it's worth being aware that the time zone mappings aren't perfect: the Windows time zone data is basically not the same source as IANA, and some zones will map to different offsets for some periods. They're updated on different schedules, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The mapping seems to be complicated. Is there a function in SQL server that I can get the date offset to UTC time from the TimeZone code?

Comment: @TonyDING: I suspect so - or a conversion to UTC (which may be ambiguous, of course). But that isn't the same as knowing the time zone itself. It makes a difference if you want to know what the local time will be a week later or something like that.